# Document named parameters with typedoc

Tags: javascript, typedoc

How do I document named parameters with typedoc? I have this JavaScript file:

```
/**
 * @param {Number} foo An interesting value
 * @param {Number} __namedParameters.bar Another value
 */
function demo({ foo=42, bar=43 } = {}) { }
```

I would like the documentation output, types, and default values to show up in the documentation.

However, neither of my attempts works, and the documentation is not helpful:

[image: typedoc outpt: __namedParameters: {} = {}]

How can I document the `foo` and `bar` named parameters?

[Here is a repository](https://github.com/phihag/typedoc-named-demo) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Appears to be a bug. Here's the [issue opened](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1274) for reference

Answer (score 0):

This [seems to be a bug](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1274) in typedoc.